# How do I implement a CSS class in a control on my web form in ASP .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I have a file in my project called StyleSheet.css.

Here, I have the classes for each element on my web form.

For example:

```
.selectEnvironment
{
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

Then I go to my control on my web form (a drop down list) and I add the CSS class to it:

```
   <div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEnvironment" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlEnvironment_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="selectEnvironment">
            <asp:ListItem>Select Environment</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Development</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Staging</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Production</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
```

This is not working. The background color of this is not changing to red.

What am I doing wrong? I'm completely new to front end web development.

Comment: Drag style sheet from Solution Explorer into you page, or master page header, in design view ;-)

Comment: ohhh this sounds FABULOUS. trying now :)

Comment: Is the class name missing from the element or are the styles themselves missing?  Inspect the element in question in your browser or view the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag style sheet from Solution Explorer into your page, or master page header, in design view. This is the easiest way to make sure that the style sheet **path** is correct ;-)

Comment: thanks irish guy! since you were the first to answer with the easiest solution, u get the green!

Answer (score 3):

You must register your style

```
    <head runat="server">

      <style type="text/css">
      ...
      </style>
    </head>
```

You can also use this line

```
<link href="MyStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

You can also register in your code Behind

```
protected override void OnInit( EventArgs e )
{
    this.Header.InnerHtml += "<link type=\"text/css\" rel=\"Stylesheet\" href=\"styleSheet.css\" />";
    base.OnInit(e);
}
```

Comment: the code is not on the web page, though. it's on a separate css file in my asp .net project

Comment: How do you know where his style sheet is located?

Comment: it's just sample IrishChieftain of registering, because the first problem is missing of regustering

Answer (score 2):

1. Add your style to the head portion of the MASTER PAGE. Or link the CSS.
2. Then add the CSSCLASS to the dropdown menu.
3. Run and see the magic. It will work.

Check below. [image]

LET ME KNOW IF THAT HELPS.

Regards,

Pradie

Comment: Don't encourage inline CSS ;-)